# FFmpeg Commands to add text watermark to mpg2,mss,lxf,3g2 video files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark, video-watermarking

I am using following command to add watermark on a video file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg2 -vf "drawtext=text='Hello World':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" TextOutput.mpg2
```

Error with mpg2 input file:

> Input #0, mpeg, from 'mpg2.mpg2':
> Duration: 00:02:27.07, start:0.213367, bitrate: 4419 kb/s
> Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470m/bt4 70m, bottom first), 704x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 22:15],
> 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn,59.94 tbc
> Side data:
> cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 6000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
> Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s [NULL @ 000000bd67d2b3c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for
> 'Output.mp g2'
> Output.mpg2: Invalid argument

Similar error occurs with mss, lxf and 3g2 video files.
How can I add watermark to these video file formats?

Comment: We need to see the commands and the complete logs for each format that fails. Just telling us that it fails requires us to make uninformed guesses and not answers.

Comment: Hi @llogan, I have added the error above. Can you please help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does not support these arbitrary extensions/formats. Instead, use:

| Unsupported | Supported equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| `.mpg2` | `-c:v mpeg2video output.mpg` |
| `.mss` | `.wmv` |
| `.lxf` | Not supported (or use `.mpg`) |
| `.3g2` | This is supported but is constrained to certain parameters. See below. |

## 3G2

The output must be:

- Mono audio with 8000 Hz sample rate. (Assuming you want AMR audio.)
- One of the following audio bitrates: 4.75k, 5.15k, 5.90k, 6.70k, 7.40k, 7.95k, 10.20k, 12.20k, 12.20k (Assuming you want AMR audio.)
- One of the following video sizes: 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576, and 1408x1152.

If it fails then look at the error messages. They will tell you what is wrong.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -s 352x288 -b:a 10.2k output.3g2
```

Comment: Hi @llogan,
I found this command: ffmpeg -i input.mpeg2 -f  vob -vf "drawtext=text='Opentext':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24: fontcolor=white" Output.mpeg2 

is able to perform the transformation. can you please check this and give me indepth detail about it?

Comment: @AvinashModi That works because you are forcing usage of the VOB muxer with `-f vob`, so `ffmpeg` will therefore not use the output file name extension to automatically choose the appropriate muxer. It will ignore the extension and would work with any arbitrary name you give it, such as `Output.Avinash`. In this case the output format is VOB no matter what you name the output file.

Comment: Hi @llogan,I thank you so much for you help!
Can you please share any article where I can find all these information and much more?

Comment: I would like to ask one more question, Will there be any issues in adding Watermark to asf, dv, rm, gxf input video files using shared command?

Comment: @AvinashModi No. You should be able to add a watermark to any video.

Comment: Hi @llogan, do 3gp video watermarking supported like 3g2(requires video size,audio bit rates)?

Comment: @AvinashModi Yes, 3gp video watermarking supported like 3g2(requires video size,audio bit rates)